# How to send small amount of BTC to thousands of addresses?

Tags: transactions, address, mining-pools, transaction-fees

I'd like to create a pool of addresses using Blockchain.com API.
But because of the gap limit on unused addresses I want to transfer minimal amount (ideally 1 Satoshi) and without any fees.
What's the easiest way to send small amount of BTC to thousands of addresses?
I don't care about speed as this is a background operation.

UPD: This is NOT a question "how to create addresses?" this is a question how to distribute small amount of money to multiple addresses with minimal fees. It is not related to  any service provider, Blockchain.com was indicated as a context only.

Comment: This is really a service problem that you have with blockchain.com that they don't have a configurable gap limit flooding transactions is a really lazy solution. There is naturally a high cost to this sort of behavior, which you can't bypass.

Comment: blockchain.com has a configurable gap limit, however this is just to create addresses, not to track them. I can afford reasonable fees, just want to minimize it.

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsensical. You don't need to send money to an address to create it.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this is by making a regular transaction with lots of outputs. Moreover, you will have great difficulty broadcasting a transaction with outputs of 1 Satoshi due to the dust limit.

A far easier solution would be to switch to a wallet provider that allows you to bypass the gap limit, such as bitgo (although it may be restricted to their commercial offering), or build your own transaction indexing system

Comment: Blockchain.com CAN create addresses beyond gap limit, it is just useles as it doesn't track them.
It could be 1000 Satoshi or more if this helps.

Comment: Creating addresses is not the hard part. Sending BTC to them to avoid the gap limit is not a viable solution, and your time/money would likely be better spent integrating a system that does not have a gap limit issue.